# @Test is not executing - If I add TestNG Listener in test xml file, my @Test methods are not executing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports, testng.xml, testng-annotation-test

I'm using TestNG and for reporting using extent report. I'm trying to add TestNG Listeners to perform some operation on Success and on Failure. I have created a Test Listener class and mentioned listener in suite file.Issue is Test is not executing and console says Test run =0 ; If is remove listener tag from suite xml file, it works like charm.

**Listener class**

```
public class TestListener implements ITestListener
{

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("OnTestStart");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Reporter.log(Status.INFO, "Passed");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Reporter.log(Status.INFO, "Failed");
    }
}
```

**Base Test**

```
public class BaseTest 
{
    @BeforeSuite
    public void preStep(ITestContext txt)
    {
        System.out.println("in before suite");
        Reporter.startReport(txt);
        System.out.println("out");
    }
    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
    public void setUp()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method");
        Reporter.setup();
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void closeUp(ITestResult tr)
    {
        System.out.println("After Method");
    }
    @AfterSuite
    public void postStep()
    {
        System.out.println("After Suite");
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```
public class TestScripts extends BaseTest
{

    @Test
    @Parameters("Browser")
    public void loginScenario(String browser)
    {
        LoginPageSteps lp = new LoginPageSteps(browser);
        lp.loginScenario();
    }
    @Test
    @Parameters("Browser")
    public void a(String browser)
    {
        Reporter.log(Status.PASS, "A Passed");
    }
    @Test
    @Parameters("Browser")
    public void b(String browser)
    {
        Reporter.log(Status.ERROR, "B Failed");
    }
    @Test
    @Parameters("Browser")
    public void c(String browser)
    {
        Reporter.log(Status.ERROR, "C Failed");
    }
}
```

**Suite File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="10" name="Default Suite" parallel="tests">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="testng.framework.utilities.TestListener"/>
  </listeners>
  <test thread-count="10" name="GUI" parallel="tests">
    <classes>
      <class name="testng.alltest.TestScripts">
        <parameter name="Browser" value="Chrome"/>
        <methods>
          <include name="a"/>
          <include name="b"/>
          <include name="c"/>
          <include name="loginScenario"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

**Output**

[image]

Kindly correct me what i'm missing out, Thanks in advance

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ORORA</groupId>
  <artifactId>UIAutomation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>UIAutomation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>Deepak Mahalingam</id>
            <name>Deepak</name>
            <email>mahalingamd@hcl.com</email>
            <organization>HCL</organization>
            <roles>
                <role>Automation Tester</role>
            </roles>
        </developer>
    </developers>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>TestSuite\TestDesktop.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>testng.framework.utilities.BuildTestXML</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: can you post you pom dependencies?

Comment: @Sureshmani please find the pom.xml file

Comment: @Deepak_Mahalingam : have you provide the full TestListener  class code ... as I can see that many methods of ITestListeners are not implemented in your class

Comment: @Deepak_Mahalingam : Can you please provide the import statement of Reporter Class which you have used in "TestListener" and "BaseTest"

Comment: If you are using Reporter class for extent reports, its available only extent report version below 4. please check the Reporter class dependency & update accordingly.

Comment: @Deepak_Mahalingam : have you tried provided solution

Comment: @PritamMaske: yes have implemented, it works fine

Comment: @Deepak_Mahalingam : Could you please accept the answer if it has solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that there is issue with **your Listener** class and **Reporter
>   class import statement** .
>
> If your are using Reporter class of TestNG then **there is no such
>   method as "setup"** or start

**I am able to run the script by modifying your TestListener and BaseTest class as follows:**

```
package stackoverflow;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class TestListener implements ITestListener {

@Override
public void onTestStart(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    System.out.println("onTestStart");
}

@Override
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    System.out.println("onTestSuccess");
}

@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    System.out.println("onTestFailure");
}

@Override
public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    System.out.println("onTestSkipped");
}

@Override
public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    System.out.println("onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage");
}

@Override
public void onStart(ITestContext iTestContext) {
    System.out.println("onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage");
}

@Override
public void onFinish(ITestContext iTestContext) {
    System.out.println("onFinish");
}
}
```

**My Base Test Class :**

```
package stackoverflow;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class BaseTest {
    @BeforeSuite
    public void preStep(ITestContext txt)
    {
        System.out.println("in before suite");
        System.out.println("out");
    }
    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
    public void setUp()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method");
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void closeUp(ITestResult tr)
    {
        System.out.println("After Method");
    }
    @AfterSuite
    public void postStep()
    {
        System.out.println("After Suite");
    }
}
```

**My TestNg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="10" name="Default Suite" parallel="tests">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="listener.TestListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <test thread-count="10" name="GUI" parallel="tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="stackoverflow.TestScripts">
                <parameter name="Browser" value="Chrome"/>
                <methods>
                    <include name="a"/>
                    <include name="b"/>
                    <include name="c"/>
                    <include name="loginScenario"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```